# Two CSS columns - when width shrinks right hand column goes to bottom of left hand column

Tags: css, css-float

On the left we have a context sensitive navigation/information bar. At times there is very little information in it and other times it takes up the entire height of the page. I've seen a bunch of suggestions on other posts about floating, etc but nothing I've tried works.

```
.tablebox {float:left;position:relative;z-index:1;border-right:1px solid #000000;}
.groupbox {float:left;position:relative;z-index:-1;border-right:1px solid #000000;}
```

So two divs for the sidebar - one to create the background layer which will take up the entire height of the page and then tablebox with the actual content on it - it could have a different background color as required.

```
<div class="tablebox" style="margin-top:5px;width:247px;">Sidebar</div>
<div class="groupbox" style="width:247px;background-color:#FFFFFF;top:120px;bottom:0;left:0px;"></div>
```

Then we have the right hand side main content... again the idea being that tablebox would have a different background colour and appear to float on top of the page.

```
<div class="tablebox" style="margin-top:5px;width:777px;">Main content</div>
<div class="groupbox" style="width:777px;top:120px;bottom:0;left:247px;"></div>
```

Now if the browser width gets to be too small the right hand div falls below the sidebar. Whether there's room there or not.

**SOLUTION:**
The problem was that the two sets of divs's parent did not have a defined size. As the browser window was resized the children got shuffled to fit inside of the new size. By defining a parent div with a fixed width and adding a overflow:auto the parent would not change even if the browser window was.

Note: This is not the best way to resolve this obviously - this means that the content does not dynamically format itself. It now has a fixed width. In my case I have no other choice. It is a band aid solution but if you're in the design stage think about people viewing your page from a cellphone or old people with their low resolution screens and giant text.

To be clear for those easily confused:

```
<div style="width:1053px;overflow:auto">
<div class="tablebox" style="margin-top:5px;width:247px;">Sidebar</div>
<div class="groupbox" style="width:247px;background-color:#FFFFFF;top:120px;bottom:0;left:0px;"></div>
<div class="tablebox" style="margin-top:5px;width:777px;">Main content</div>
<div class="groupbox" style="width:777px;top:120px;bottom:0;left:247px;"></div>
</div>
```

But again - if you have a choice don't do this! Fixed width will not make your site very pretty on some devices.

Comment: Please consider using a frontend framework such as [Twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) instead of hand coding css from scratch. It really does save a lot of pain.

Comment: Sadly this is integrating into an existing php project. The ui and the backend are not separate. That would make my life much easier. I'm trying to see if there's a simple answer before I rewrite a ton of code. I'll take a look though. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Yikes, you have my sympathy and best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }
        div {
            width:25%;
            height:25%;
        }
        div.left {
            background-color:red;
            float:left;
        }
        div.right {
            background-color:yellow;
            float:right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8gNDU/2/

Comment: @Huza: First try the above code in an html file, you will get the answer to your question

Comment: Please try to use percentages instead of px because that will make your web applications responsive and not only the movements while resizing be fluid but they will be free of javascript etc, otherwise even I am redsgning my website using bootstrap for rapid deployment

Comment: Yes - setting up percentages and better support for all is on my to-do list. Sadly there are higher priorities right now.

Comment: same here, I want to transform but I can't, but in the answer I am hinting to use `float:right` that's all :D plz upvote if you find it the correct solution to your problem